# java.io.IOException: No route to host using MulticastSocket on MacOS X Snow Leopard

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard, multicast, routes

I have a java application using multicast in order to advertise some entity - all worked fine when I tried the application a couple of weeks back. However, this is not the case anymore: I'm getting a

```
java.io.IOException: No route to host
```

exception when the unchanged application is started again. The application is sending DatagramPackets to 224.0.0.1.

My current system is Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.7) with Java 1.6.0_24 installed.

I've tried out several approaches with the following outcomes:
 - search google -> some suggestions, none of which helped so far
 - disable firewall -> not successful
 - disable network interface (to force it to use the loopback) -> not successful
 - running it on Win machine -> successful, so I assume it definitely has something to do with the current (or changed/updated) system configuration

Any pointers or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: everything else on that machine can get to that address?  ping/traceroute, etc?

Comment: that was my guess as well: what about icmp messages in general but that is perfectly fine. i maybe should point out that i'm testing it locally - so no real network in between as of now.

Comment: going to see whether wireshark helps me understand the matter a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No route to host` is caused by your process receiving an ICMP "host unreachable" message from some router on the path between you and the destination IP.  Since you're getting this on a multicast address, I'd suspect something wrong with your router configuration.

Comment: it can also be caused right at the sending host by not finding the initial route, which points to the routing tables.

Comment: but how come then that the application ran 3 weeks ago and now it doesn't anymore? If I add an entry in the host's routing table, what would be a suitable netmask to do so? Would 'route add 224.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 en1' be appropriate?